# How to use onblur and onchange in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to use onblur and onchange in jsp file
I have a form with tables that contains several radio and selecbox input fields. Essentially, I need to handle the onchange event for all fields and the onblur events for some fields. When a change is made to a field and the field loses focus, both events fire (which is the correct behavior).

Actullay my expected output is when i change radio button the selected radio buttons selctbox will enable and others will disabled. how it will achieve

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead style="height: 60px; overflow: auto;">
        <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;color: teal;width: 5%;padding: 1%;"></th>
        <th style="text-align: center;color: teal;width: 5%;padding: 1%;">#</th>
        <th style="color: teal;width: 15%;text-align: center;padding: 1%;">Pedagogy</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
        int index = 0;
        for (Map<String, Object> eachLessonPlanDaily : lessonPlanDailys) 
        {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;width: 5%;">
            <%
            if(studentList.get(0).get("lessonPlanId") != null && studentList.get(0).get("lessonPlanId").equals(eachLessonPlanDaily.get("_id").toString())) {
            %>    
                <input type="radio" id="lessonPlanId" name="lessonPlanId" value="<%=eachLessonPlanDaily.get("_id").toString()%>" onblur="javascript:selectlpdblur(<%=index%>)" onchange="javascript:selectlpd(<%=index%>)" checked="checked">
            <%
            }
            else {
            %>       
                <input type="radio" id="lessonPlanId" name="lessonPlanId" value="<%=eachLessonPlanDaily.get("_id").toString()%>" onblur="javascript:selectlpdblur(<%=index%>)" onchange="javascript:selectlpd(<%=index%>)">
            <%
            }
            %>
            </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;width: 5%; "><%=index+1%></td>
        <td style="width: 15%;text-align: justify; ">
            <select name="pedagogylp" id="pedagogylp-<%=index%>" value="this.value" onchange="javascript:selectlpd(<%=index%>)" disabled="true">
                <option value="select">-------------select-------------</option>
                <%
                Iterator iterator = pedagogyList.entrySet().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                    if(eachLessonPlanDaily.get("pedagogy") != null && eachLessonPlanDaily.get("pedagogy").equals(mapEntry.getValue())){
                    %>
                        <option selected value="<%=mapEntry.getKey()%>"><%=mapEntry.getValue()%></option>
                    <%
                    }
                    else {
                    %>
                        <option value="<%=mapEntry.getKey()%>"><%=mapEntry.getValue()%></option>
                    <% 
                    }
                }
                %>
            </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
       <%
       index++;
                }
       %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
function selectlpd(val) {
    alert("ok........."+val)
    document.getElementById("pedagogylpd").value = document.getElementById("pedagogylp-"+val).value;
    document.getElementById("pedagogylp-"+val).disabled=false;
}

function selectlpdblur(val) {
    alert("ok.blur........"+val)
    document.getElementById("toynamelp-"+val).disabled=true;
}
```

Comment: show us where you added your javacript in HTML, please.

Comment: @tfidelis inside head tag my script is placed working fine but i need two times to chnage radio button thats my problem

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) for us? it's hard to see what's happening without being able to debbug. put your HTML loaded, without serverside code.

Comment: @tfidelis ayyyo how can i create this.

Comment: go to your page, press `control + u`, copy your HTML and put inside your question for us (edit your question and include your HTML), i will create a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing "javascript:" from the attributes 'onchange' and 'onblur' (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp). Your code looks okay otherwise, use F12 option (developer console) in the browser to debug.

Comment: Dear Asish Ji its working fine but i need two times to click to change one radio button to another